# How does "this" in onClick work?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, onclick

I'm new to javascript. I'm curious how does the browser makes an `onClick` attribute work.
You have this in a html:

```
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</button>
```

what does a browser do to execute a the (allways javascript?) script function?

I guess this is something like eval-ing the string that is given to the onClick.

But I have doubts like these: What is the applying standard here? How does the browser know which script language to use? How is `this` filled up by the javascript engine? In what context does the script execute? What happens with a return value? What do I want to read to know what can I rely on when working with these attributes?

Can you help me to understand what's going on?

Comment: You want us to write a book here?

Comment: @JayantVarshney Sorry, no, not intended; on the contrary, just wish if you could to point me in the right direction (that's why I've tried to label my list of questions as 'doubts', not actually asking them, just trying to explain what my problem is). A few directions like close terms I can search for and a very vague overview of what is happening would do. I just couldn't find anything on web search because "this" is too ambiguous as a keyword, and I don't know the right terms. And the web is also full of 'how-to-use'-like tutorials which makes the result not very good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set an *onclick* attribute; the browser takes the reference to the node you've set it on, let's call this reference `button`, and then does the transfomation

```
onclick="/* code */"
```

to

```
button.onclick = function (event) {eval(/* code */);};
```

When a *click* event is then tirggered, the function can be thought of as being invoked like this

```
button.onclick.call(button, click_event);
```

Giving the `onclick` the context of `button`, and hence `this` is `button`. It is wrapped in it's own *function* so if something is `var`d it will not be set in the global scope.

---

> What happens with a return value?

Returning `false` is the equivalent of calling [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), exact behaviour is described [**here**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm).

---

> How does the browser know which script language to use?

Assumes *JavaScript* unless explicitly stated otherwise

---

> What do I want to read to know what can I rely on when working with these attributes?

Don't learn these *HTML* attributes, they are dated, can be dangerous and mix your *HTML* and *JavaScript* together. Instead learn to use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: That use of "eval" is incorrect, because that code would destroy the value of `this` inside the executed code.  Try `new Function(/*code*/)` as a better description.

Comment: @cloudfeet `(function () {eval('console.log(this);');}).call(document.body);` logs `<body>`

Comment: @cloudfeet I purposely used `eval` to emphasise that setting an _onclick_ in _HTML_ can be dangerous (without explicitly saying it).. and yes, I didn't use `new Function` because it's easier to read `function` too

Comment: Note to self: re-read ECMAScript specification again ([relevant portion](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2), step 2)

Comment: I knew there was *something* fishy with `eval()` and `this` - if you do `var a = eval; a(...)` then it's reset to the global context.

Comment: @cloudfeet yes, `eval` has some weird internal `eval.apply(this, args)` going on, but you shouldn't need worry about it because it is **dangerous and to be avoided where possible**

Answer (score 4):

Phew, that's a lot of questions!

> Q. what does a browser do to execute a the (allways javascript?) script function
>
> Q. How does the browser know which script language to use

**A.** Modern browsers always assume Javascript, unless it is prefixed with a label, e.g. `onclick="vbscript:alert('Hello World!');"`

> Q. How is this filled up by the javascript engine

**A.** `this` always refers to the element on which the `onclick` was added, in this case the `button` element

> Q. In what context does the script execute

**A.** The script executes at window scope.

> Q. What happens with a return value

**A.** The return value determines whether or not the browser should continue executing the default code for this element. If the button is a submit button and you return `false`, your form will not be posted

> Q. What do I want to read to know what can I rely on when working with these attributes

**A.** A Javascript book. Have a look at the top Javascript books on Amazon.

Comment: Good answer RGraham, keep it up.

Comment: I've accepted Paul's answer because it gives a better overview of the process, but this answer is great, too!

Comment: One could find many Javascript books, but do ones for Javascript usually go under the hood like this? Many introductory book in general just list syntax to stick to and available language elements and they not always explain what is under their hood. I expected not a book title, but still something specific to look for, like the 'feature name', or "section X.Z of the ecmascript standard found at Y", but wasn't sure it's in the specs or not.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers assume JavaScript, basically because although it could *in theory* be any scripting language, in practice JavaScript has won.

It executes the code in `onclick` with `this` being the element for which the click event was triggered.

The return value is used exactly the same way as for `element.onclick = function () {...}`.

In fact, the whole thing works equivalently to:

```
var element = document.getElementById('1');
element.onclick = new Function(element.getAttribute('onclick'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does the browser know which script language to use?

You need to write out `<script>` tags inorder to write script. The default script is JavaScript if no script type is implied. 
If you're using various JavaScript libraries or similar like jQuery then you need to use $ or jQuery infront of your calls.

> What happens with a return value?

There is no real return value. It basically is what happens in the function you call with your onClick.